# C: Array of pointers vs pointer-to-pointer

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, pointer-to-pointer

Do these two pieces of C code achieve the same goal:

```
char ** p;
p = malloc(sizeof(char*) * 10);

--------------------------------

char * z[10];
```

It seems like they can be used identically:

```
p[1] = "Foo";
*(p+2) = "Bar";

---------------------

z[1] = "Foo";
*(z+2) = "Bar";
```

Is there a difference?

Comment: What do you think? What have you done to find out yourself? What **specifically** don't you understand?

Comment: I've played around with both forms and can't find a difference.  I was just wondering if there's something I've missed.

Comment: Yes, you did miss some chapters in your C book. For a starter: try `sizeof(p) == sizeof(z)`

Comment: Also consider the difference between a *pointer-to-pointer-to-type* and an *array-of-pointers*. If the difference isn't immediately clear, you have found the root of your problem in understanding. Neither of those are the same as a *pointer-to-array-of-type*.

Comment: It is the same as the difference between `char s[10];` and `char *ps = malloc(10);`

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1641957/is-an-array-name-a-pointer-in-c

Comment: I see.  Thanks.  This is much clearer now.

Comment: @vjb: you should read that, it's pretty interesting http://publications.gbdirect.co.uk/c_book/chapter5/arrays_and_address_of.html

Comment: @romain-aga: Thanks.  That looks like a handy guide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just store and retrieve values from the array, or malloc-allocated area, they work the same.

There are differences, though. `sizeof` and `&` work differently, you need to explicitly `free` the malloc-allocated area to release the memory, and you can change its size with `realloc`.

Comment: Ah, nice.  Thanks.  So use pointer-to-pointer if you need to dynamically resize a structure similar to an array?

Comment: @vjb: If you need your array (or "array") to shrink and grow dynamically, or yes, use `malloc` to allocate it.

Answer (score 0):

in terms of use and functionality, there really is no difference except in how you plan to use it.

An example of what I mean is that I could use a double pointer for iterating and dereferencing the whole multidim array.

not to mention that when you `malloc`, you need a matching `free` when you're done with it.

Of course, you should only `malloc` when you think you really need it or you need a massive amount of memory.

Last part I want to say is that with the pointer array, you cannot dereference the individual characters without using the subscript operator `[]`

Answer (score -1):

C memory is split into several types, **stacks** -for function calls and local variables, and then there is **heap** -for malloced objects. The stack usually has smaller size than the heap. As a result, if you try to allocate a huge array in stack you might exceed the stack's storage space causing segfault.

In this case when you malloc an array, heap memory is being used .And it will exist until it is explicitly deallocated with free. This is useful in cases where you are using large array size.
Whereas in the first case you are declaring the array in stack,which lives only as long as the function that calls it exists.

Since the array size is small here, both works. But for larger arrays, malloc'ing is recommended to avoid segfault.